# Super automatic real-time collaboration framework for browser-based applications? (See specifications in question body)

Tags: javascript, framework, collaboration

I have a non-collaborative web app, and I've been researching frameworks for real-time collaboration web apps. There are a ton of them out there and many are not very well documented, so I feel like I'm just not getting anywhere. I've looked at [meteor](https://www.meteor.com), [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [mojito](https://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/), and a lot of other ones, but I find it's hard to get the information I need without going all out and becoming an expert in each framework one at a time.

Any experts know if there are real-time web app frameworks that have a development process like the following?

1. Start with a non-collaborative web app that is not tightly bound to any specific backend framework (mine is a non-collaborative drawing app that only relies on the server to hold saved files. everything else is done client-side)
2. Mark the appropriate objects/data fields as shared.
3. Set editing permissions per user and object/data field
4. Optionally turn off auto-update and insert the update function in the appropriate spots in the javascript (still not sure if I want to use auto-update or not).

And then the final product would push changes whenever any shared data field's value changes on the client of a user who has permission (auto-update), or whenever you call the update function on an object/data field.

If there isn't something that auto-updates, I can live with calling update all the time.

Anyone know of a framework that's kind of like that?

FWIW [Here's a comparison of the three tools I mention](https://gist.github.com/clarle/3396225).